# While executing a shell script I created a .txt file, edited it, after saving the script exits

Tags: bash, shell, vim

```
echo "some content" >file.txt

vim file.txt;

echo " Edited the file successfully" 

echo "Should we proceed with some task (y/n)"

read input </dev/tty

case $input
y ) do some task
n ) exit
```

What happens is the file opens I am able to edit the file and after
saving the file it executes the echo and then exits.

It gives me an error like this before I am able to edit the file.

```
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
```

Comment: Are you running the script with standard input redirected?

Comment: Your `case` statement is not correct syntax, you're missing `;;` after each case and you're missing `esac` at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input is redirected, use:

```
vim file.txt </dev/tty
```

to redirect back to the terminal while running `vim`.